# how to avoid jquery content flashes when DOM is loading

Tags: jquery, html, dom, pageload

I have a few very simple jQuery functions running after the document is ready. For example:

```
$('div.std br').remove();
```

I use this because Magento's TinyMCE editor constantly throws in annoying `<br />`'s if you have any whitespace leftover. This works great but obviously while the page is loading I have to look at the ugly content with all the `<br />`s in it, then it flashes and executes the function which is even more distracting.

Is there a way to prevent this or should I be hiding the content until it is loaded as similar articles on the subject suggest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ...should I be hiding the content until it is loaded...?

Yes. You might want to preserve the space in the layout to avoid an annoying "jump" too.

CSS:

```
div.str {
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

JS to be placed *right after the div, or right before the closing `</body>` tag*:

```
<script>
    $("div.str").find("br").remove();
    $("div.str").css("visibility", "visible");
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think div tags can fire a `load` event, since they don't natively.

Comment: Hang on, did you try @ggreiner's solution? If that works, and is cross -browser, I would definitely go with his solution.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried hiding or styling `<br />` using CSS:

```
br{ 
  display: none;
}
```

Since the CSS file is probably loaded before the content itself, then by the time the content will be rendered, the `<br />` elements won't appear to begin with, and will therefore not 'flash'.

Answer (score 1):

Add this CSS rules:

```
div.std br {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to simply set the display to none on the object so that the DOM won't show it as it loads in.

```
<div id="testdiv" style="display:none">Hello</div>

...
...
...

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#testdiv').fadeIn(1000);
});
```

I have a lot of code in some of my older projects that look like this though that accomplishes the same thing:

```
<div id="testdiv" style="visibility:hidden">Hello</div>

...
...
...

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#testdiv').hide().css('visibility', 'visible');
});
```

That way they image is hidden using HTML, then JQuery hides it (so its hidden in 2 ways at this point), then the HTML is set to visible, so its just JQuery holding it invisible in the DOM at this point, then I use it like normal.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the breaks on the server-side before it gets added to the database, or before you return it as content.